# Is useCallback a better choice if the component has no child component

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

So far as i know, useCallback is kind of trick which can keep the reference of function to make the child 
component's React.memo work;

But i still have the question that the useCallback is really necessary to improve the performance if there is not child component ?

I have tried below code both with useCallback and without useCallback, and both of which work well;

```
const Demo = () => {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(1);

  // const toConsoleLogCount = () => {
  //     console.log(count)
  // }

  const toConsoleLogCount = React.useCallback(() => {
      console.log(count)
  }, [count])

  return (
      <div>
          <span>Count: {count}</span><br/>
          <button onClick={() => setCount(c => c + 1)}>Plus One</button>
          {' '}
          <button onClick={toConsoleLogCount}>Click Me </button>
      </div>
  )
}
```

I have looked up plenty of articles and get even more confused;
Can anybody explain the difference ? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You marked correctly **useCallback** keep the reference of function. But it does not make sense to use it on HTML tags, since they will always be re-rendered when updating the parent component.